# On OSSSearchResults.aspx page search text box not visible

Tags: search

on click of advance search webpart's search button it redirects to OSSSearchResults.aspx page where search text box on the top of site not visible.

Comment: Are you using a custom master page?

Comment: Yes i am using custom master page

Comment: my site logo is visible but search text not visible.

Answer (score 2):

Start troubleshooting by removing the Custom Master Page. I suspect that your designer did not account for a placeholder on the My Site Host.